# I have three given names

Tags: air-travel, tickets, airports, check-in

My full name is four names long - First name, Middle name, Middle name, Last name. However, in my Canadian passport this is the format my name was written

- Given Name : First name, Middle name, Middle name
- Last name : Last name.

I booked tickets recently and I just put first and last name (Short format).

Will this be an issue especially since in my passport my given name is 3 names.

I tried to reach out to airlines and they told me I must cancel my ticket and buy a new one.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you travelling to/from? What airline? I'm surprised by the advice given by the airline (worst case they would charge you for the change, but cancelling and rebooking seems a bit extreme).

Comment: I am travelling from Canada to Cairo via Air Maroc. 

Then flying back from Cairo to Canada via Air Canada (partially operated by Qatar airways) . Air Canada who asked me to cancel and rebook again . yea it was funny because they asked me to book a new ticket then they will cancel the previous one .

Answer (score 1):

I'm exactly in the same situation as you: 3 given names and one full name.

I don't think I've ever put anything put my first name and last name in flight bookings, and I've never had an issue with this.

This is pretty common, and as far as I know most procedures and systems are designed to handle this. Many airline ticketing systems just don't have the space for all given names anyway. Likewise the MRZ on many forms of ID has limits on how long the full name can be and are designed to deal with truncation.

If the destination/transit countries require a visa, ETA, ESTA, e-Visitor or anything else like that, however, you should provide your full name in those applications.

If the destination/overflown countries require API (Advance Passenger Information), you should provide your full name on that form. Sometimes airlines block input into the first and last name fields and re-use those from your booking, which may lead to issues automatically matching to an ESTA/ETA/e-Visitor. Worst case, they will scan the passport at check-in and use what is on your passport.